# Connect Twisted IRCClient through a http proxy

Tags: python, twisted, irc

I am playing around with Twisted and while trying to rewrite an old java IRC bot in Python (2.7), I built upon the [IrcLogBot example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html#auto6).

I need to connect to the IRC server through a (non auth) HTTP proxy - but there does not seem to be any support for this neither in the irc.IRCClient or in reactor.connectTCP. Am I looking in the wrong places? Can I wrap my connection in some kind of proxy tunneler?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the HTTP proxy you are connecting to supports CONNECT requests, this is totally doable.

Here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/2018384) that works for tunneling SSH connections over an HTTP proxy.   It should work for IRC connections as well.

With the example code, you should be able to do something like:

```
proxy = HTTPProxyConnector('myhttpproxy.server', 8080)
proxy.connectTCP('myirc.server', 6667, MyTwistedIRCClientFactory())
```

There are still some issues to work out with handling server timeouts more gracefully / quickly, but if you include some kind of periodic application or underlying protocol-level ping, it should keep both servers from timing out your connection.

Comment: @fmoo, I can confirm that this works.  I have to use the proxy settings under XChat while I'm at work.  Having http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables set is not enough.  I downloaded that gist file and ran it with the irc log bot example, works just fine.  Thanks!